# Hide Rows based on content - Speed

Tags: excel, vba

I am extremely new to coding VBA macros for excel and have mostly googled what I want to accomplish in excel and adapting others VBA code specifically to my needs.  One of my macros hides rows based on the contents of a cell.  I am finding that it takes too long to run and can make some older computers lock up.  Does anyone have any suggestions on making this run quicker with fewer resources? Below is the code that I am using:

```
Sub Hiderow()
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range 
Application.EnableEvents = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row    
On Error Resume Next 

For Each c In Range("B12:B812") 
    If c.Value = "" Then  
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = True    
    ElseIf c.Value <> "" Then    
        c.EntireRow.Hidden = False    
    End If    
Next
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have `LastRow` and never use it?

Answer (score 3):

You could alternatively use `SpecialCells()`

```
Sub hide_empty_rows()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B12:B812")
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).EntireRow.Hidden = False

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The `Application.[]` parts will help speed it up a little more.  You shouldn't really be crashing Excel with just 800 rows, so I'm assuming you have some formulas/etc that updates each time a cell gets updated.  The `SpecialCells()` should speed it up alone, but the three `Application.[]` parts are generally helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off screen updating when it is running, also remove the ElseIf and make it Else:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, c As Range
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next



  For Each c In Range("B1:B812")
      If c.Value = "" Then
      c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
      Else
      c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
      End If
    Next

On Error GoTo 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This will run faster

Comment: Would changing `ElseIf` to `Else` make a difference in speed? Even this specific instance aside, say there's 100,000 rows to check.  Does `Else` provide better 'speed' than `ElseIf`?  Perhaps because `ElseIf` has the compiler thinking there may be more conditions in that block, whereas `Else` signals the end of the `If` statement?

Comment: Thank you Mark PM! Making those two changes significantly increased the speed of the macro.  That was perfect!

Comment: @BruceWayne It will speed it up (very, very slightly) as there is no extra if so less checks! The main speed improvement will come from screen updating...

Answer (score 0):

Another option - using `AutoFilter` `+` `Rows.Hidden`

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HideEmptyRowsInColB()
    Const FIRST_ROW = 12
    Const FILTER_COL = "B"

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, hide As Range, filterCol As Range, vis As Boolean

    Set ws = Sheet3     'Or: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FILTER_COL).End(xlUp).Row

    Set filterCol = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, FILTER_COL), ws.Cells(lr, FILTER_COL))

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        ShowAllRows ws
        If lr > FIRST_ROW Then

            filterCol.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
                Set hide = filterCol.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                vis = hide.Cells.Count = 1 And Len(hide.Cells(1)) = 0   'Count visible
                Set hide = IIf(vis, Nothing, hide.EntireRow)
            filterCol.AutoFilter

            If Not hide Is Nothing Then
                hide.Hidden = True
                hide.Rows(1).Hidden = (Len(hide.Cells(1)) > 0)
            End If
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ShowAll()
    ShowAllRows Sheet3
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAllRows(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
    ws.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

---

.

---

**`Performance`**

```
AutoFilter + Rows.Hidden (Current version):

 - Total Rows:   100,001, Hidden:  49,995 - Time:   2.199 sec
 - Total Rows:   200,001, Hidden:  99,995 - Time:   8.551 sec
 - Total Rows:   300,001, Hidden: 149,995 - Time:  19.016 sec
 - Total Rows:   400,001, Hidden: 199,995 - Time:  43.594 sec
 - Total Rows:   500,001; Hidden: 249,995 - Time:  61.387 sec
 - Total Rows: 1,048,573, Hidden: 524,276 - Time: 233.301 sec (almost 4 min)

AutoFilter (Previous version):

 - Total Rows:   500,001; Hidden: 249,995 - Time:   0.211 sec
 - Total Rows: 1,048,563; Hidden: 262,144 - Time:   0.469 sec
```

Comment: Thank you, that was even faster! basically instantaneous! However, that does introduce a new problem, which is that If I want to manually unhide a row, it's seemingly not allowing me to do so. I can still manually hide rows, I just can't seem to then unhide them, if I need to.

Comment: @ChrisM - Thanks for the feedback! Yes, while the `AutoFilter` is in effect you can't unhide rows manually. I made a change where is still using the benefits of `AutoFilter`, it captures the rows to be hidden, removes the `AutoFilter`, and at the end hides all rows to be hidden. It's a bit slower if you have to work with more than 100K rows

Comment: That worked, although now there is another unintended consequence that I am unsure how it's related. On another sheet in the same file, I have macros that update automatically when cells change, using:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

The auto change works fine when I first open the file, but as soon as I hit the macro button to execute your code above, it stops.  If I save, close the file, and reopen, I can get the auto change to work again.  Any thoughts there? You've been a huge help and I appreciate all your time.

Comment: I think I got it.  I needed to add Application.EnableEvents = True at the end of your code!

Comment: @ChrisM - Nice work ! However, my code doesn't turn off events (`Application.EnableEvents = False`). It only toggles `ScreenUpdating` Off and On. You _could_ fix the issue by adding `Application.EnableEvents = True` to this code, but the problem should be fixed at the root: find which code turn OFF `Application.EnableEvents`, and place `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of that specific procedure, otherwise you spread unrelated logic to different parts of the code that do not do their own "cleanup"

Comment: ( @ChrisM - a quick check: it looks like the answer for 'Mark PM' turns off `Application.EnableEvents = False`, but it doesn't get back on  to `Application.EnableEvents = False` )